# Piped xargs doesn't execute the command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, pipe, xargs

I want to monitor nginx access.log for malformed requests and notify myself about such cases.

To do this i have written following command:

```
tail -n0 -f access.log | grep --line-buffered '\{' | xargs sentry-cly -m
```

But this solution doesn't work for some reason. 
If i remove last pipe and end with grep only - i will see output as log file get new records.

I don't understand why xargs not executed. 
It will be the same if you replace sentry-cli with cat or echo.

Could you clarify why I have such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `xargs` collects input until it has as much as it thinks it can safely pass to a single invocation of the utility (in this case `sentry-cly -m`). That means it'll wait until it's seen a large number of log messages, then run `sentry-cly -m first message second message third message ... thousandth message ...`. To avoid this, use `xargs -L1 sentry-cly -m` -- the `-L1` tells it to run`sentry-cly -m` for every line it reads (i.e. for each message).

(Similarly, `xargs -L2 sentry-cly -m` would wait until it'd gotten 2 messages then run `sentry-cly -m "firstmessage" "secondmessage"`, then wait for the next two... You can see this by running `xargs -L2 echo`, and then typing lines into it and watching what gets echoed when.)

Answer (score 2):

After some further investigation I found that following solution works:
`xargs -L 1`.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you add a sentence to explain what that does and clarify whether that is the entire command?

Comment: Gordon already provided a good exmplanation